# ¿Cómo cambio el grupo principal de un usuario?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Cuando estoy creando ficheros/directorios con mi usuario: **jose**, el grupo de estos siempre es **docker**. Es como si tuviera una máscara o algo pero no existe nada de esto.

Pongo un ejemplo:

1º Creo directorio test:

```
▶ mkdir test
```

2º Miro permisos, usuarios y grupos:

```
▶ ls -ls | grep test
   4 drwxr-xr-x 2 jose docker    4096 ago 31 09:36 test
```

Como se puede observar aparece **docker** como grupo en vez de **jose**.
¿A qué se podría estar debiendo esto?

Comment: No soy experto en Unix y esto puede que sea una tontería pero ¿has verificado a qué grupos pertenece tu usuario y cuál es el primario? Entiendo que el grupo docker no habrá aparecido de la nada. A lo mejor al instalar Docker has pulsado una Y de más y se ha establecido como primario.

Comment: ¿Qué te da `groups jose`? El primero que salga será el que se le asigne. Muy probablemente, "docker".

Comment: Docker lo cree cuando instalee docker por temas de standar de tenga su propio user y group, pero para docker no para mi user. Efectivamente `groups jose` me devuelve  en primer lugar `docker` , o sea que de alguna manera tengo que poner mi user el primero no ? . Cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo ? . Muchas gracias !!

Comment: Vale, ya lo he cambiado pero sigue generandolo con group docker, y ahora si esta jose como grupo prinipal

Comment: Cierra sesión y vuelve a abrir, pues seguramente carga estos datos al abrir la sesión.

Comment: Perfecto, solucionado queda ! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema consistía en que tu usuario tenía como grupo principal a "docker" en lugar de "jose".

#### Para ver los grupos a los que pertenece un usuario

```
groups <usuario>
```

#### Para cambiar el grupo principal de un usuario

```
usermod -g <grupo_principal> <usuario>
```

---

Una vez hecho esto, toda nueva sesión ya tendrá el grupo *grupo_principal* como principal.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias !

Comment: Bro, ¿Como puedo saber que usuarios pertenecen a un grupo x?

Comment: @AgileSoul ¿bro?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', disculpa por llamarte bro, solo quiero saber eso.

Comment: @AgileSoul [How can I find out which users are in a group within Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241216/)